# How would I find the 2nd smallest number in a given set of double variables

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class TwoSmallest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
Double mintwo = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            Double temp = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
            if(temp < min){
                min = temp;
            }
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        Double temp2 = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);

        if(temp2 < mintwo && temp2 != min){
                mintwo = temp2;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(mintwo); 
    }
 }
```

Im trying to find the smallest and 2nd smallest in a set of numbers, im not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: What is the issue with the code you have now?

Comment: it just prints  the min value both times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to iterate the array of doubles once.  Then, we can use the following logic when deciding what to do with incoming values:

- If the value be less than the smallest, then assign it as the smallest and *also* promote the previous smallest to the second smallest
- If the value be greater than the smallest, but less than the second smallest, then just assign it to the second smallest
- Otherwise, do nothing

Here is your updated code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    Double mintwo = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
        Double temp = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
        if (temp < min) {
            mintwo = min;
            min = temp;
        }
        else if (temp < mintwo) {
            mintwo = temp;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(mintwo);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful, I was shocked at how deceptively the answer was, I guess I was overthinking.

Comment: @PM the answer was mine, this dude only stole it, but nevermind.

Comment: @ Villat I tried yours but I wasn't working for certain conditions, similar to previous trys. I'm sorry, but it did work. I do appreciate your help though :)